# Cmake headers: if the header exists in "X" directory, use it. Otherwise, use the header in "Y" directory. Is this possible?

Tags: c++, c, installation, cmake, build

I am working with a relatively old code base which has a lot of header files with duplicate names. For example:

```
dir
 ↪ subdir1
   ↪ header1.h
   ↪ header2.h
 ↪ subdir2
   ↪ header2.h
```

For reasons I won't get into here, this structure must remain as-is. I am looking for a way to build/install these headers in such a way that:

```
for all headers:
  if header in subdir2: use it
  else: use header from subdir1
```

From my example, this would mean I use `subdir1/header1.h` and `subdir2/header2.h`, while ignoreing `subdir1/header2.h` completely.
I wrote some functions to handle this in my cmake files (basically following the pseudo-code provided above), but they are sloppy. I am looking for a built-in way to handle this type of thing, rather then DIY bandaids.

Comment: *"if header in subdir1: use it"* means that you want `subdir1/header1.h` and `subdir1/header2.h` while ignoring `subdir2/header2.h`. But that's not what you said in the sentence *"From my example ..."* So which is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the CMake code implementing the pseudo-code. It is difficult to suggest improvements without seeing a current implementation. AFAIK, there is no "built-in" mechanism for this.

Comment: You could create a symlink to Y if the header X doesn't exist, and then always include X.

Comment: Or create a dummy header in X that includes Y. This is what most projects do.

Comment: Ah, sorry, typo. Fixed. It should have been _"if header in subdir2: use it"_

Comment: If you want both `#include <header1.h>` and `#include <header2.h>` to work and resolve them to `subdir1/header1.h` and `subdir2/header2.h` correspondingly, then just add `subdir2` as include directory **before** `subdir1`. E.g. `include_directories(subdir2 subdir1)`.